# Sending commands to an empty variable

Tags: python, arrays, null

In my script I'm having to run several functions within a class by using `if __name__ == "__main__"` but I am unable to adjust the functions within the class due to other people needing to use it for other purposes. The class expects a number of objects to be passed in (these objects are essentially empty arrays that can be filled with certain commands). If I pass in `None` instead, what will happen when the class functions try to perform operations on them? I presume it will crash because the object's functions will no longer be defined if there is no object. However, is there perhaps a way to ignore these commands by doing something outside of the class? I know try-except would probably work, but I'm trying to avoid making any edits to the class, if at all possible.

Comment: If you add some short code snippet that clarifies the problem, you are likely to get an answer sooner.

Comment: What? It sounds like you may want to **mock** some objects, but without more details it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Sorry hard to phrase - I believe I am trying to mock objects. Basically, they are unnecessary for my purposes, but I still have to account for them in my script. Function calls to the objects are along the lines of `report.add_line("blah")` and so on. But I have set `report = None`. Is there anything I can do on the outside of a class that will cause the class's functions to ignore calls for the `None` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, you want to pass some mock objects to third-party scripts. Consider using [mock library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/%20mock%20library) for python 2.x (which is available as  for [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=mock#module-unittest.mock) for python >= 3.3) to instantiate objects the objects that functions expect for.

**NB** But please, if the code in question is written by your colleagues do discuss with them some changes in their code that would simplify both your work and the clarity of the logic and will keep the code safe from mockups.